# index a library then search for a word in the library and record all possible matches

Tags: excel, vba, function, ms-access

I have a database of about 400,000 records and would like to search the index result of these to another column to check if it exists or not. I would like it to record even if only a partial string exists. I have an example I have tried in Excel. It takes a very long time to process 100,000 records (4 hours) with 4 cores at 2.8ghz. I figured doing this in MS Access will be faster. Can this be done faster in MS Access? I will paste the code here...

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A:$A)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,$A:$A))),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this in MS Access with VBA code or a query.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more info about your database, what you have tried and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done although I am not sure it will be faster. Have a table of the library strings and another table for the database strings.

Option using queries requires a unique identifier field in each table. The text strings might serve for that purpose but I recommend a number. If not already in each table add an autonumber field.

Consider:

Query1: LibDB

```
SELECT [DB_ID]+[LIB_ID] AS ID, DB.WordDB, Lib.WordLib 
FROM Lib, DB
WHERE (((InStr([WordLib],[WordDB]))>0))
ORDER BY DB.WordDB, Lib.WordLib;
```

Query2

```
TRANSFORM First(LibDB.WordLib) AS FirstOfWordLib
SELECT LibDB.WordDB
FROM LibDB
GROUP BY LibDB.WordDB
PIVOT DCount("*","LibDB","WordDB='" & [WordDB] & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

This is very fast with sample data provided but may perform so slowly with large dataset as to be non-functional.

For a VBA approach, create a table Result with fields named WordDB, F1, F2, etc. Include as many Fn fields as might be needed up to 254. Then procedure in a general module like:

```
Sub StringMatch()
Dim rsDB As DAO.Recordset, rsLIB As DAO.Recordset, rsRST As DAO.Recordset, n As Integer
Set rsDB = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT WordDB FROM DB ORDER BY WordDB")
Set rsRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Result WHERE 1=1")
n = 1
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Result"
Do While Not rsDB.EOF
    rsRST.AddNew
    Set rsLIB = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT WordLib FROM Lib " & _
                "WHERE InStr([WordLib],'" & rsDB!WordDB & "') > 0 ORDER BY WordLib;")
    rsRST!WordDB = rsDB!WordDB
    Do While Not rsLIB.EOF And n < 255
        rsRST("F" & n) = rsLIB!WordLib
        n = n + 1
        rsLIB.MoveNext
        If rsLIB.EOF Then
            rsRST.Update
            n = 1
        End If
    Loop
    rsLIB.Close
    rsDB.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Regardless of method, output is limited to 255 columns.

If you want to stay with Excel, open recordsets of column data and feed results to cells. No idea if this will be faster than your Excel function or Access.

```
Dim rsLIB As New ADODB.Recordset, rsDB As New ADODB.Recordset, c As Integer, r As Integer
Dim cnx As New ADODB.Connection
'setup the connection
'[HDR=Yes] means the Field names are in the first row
cnx.Open "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';" & _
         "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
         "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
rsDB.Open "SELECT Database FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE NOT Database Is Null", _
     cnx, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
c = 3
r = 2
Do While Not rsDB.EOF
    rsLIB.Open "SELECT Library FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
               "WHERE InStr([Library],'" & rsDB!Database & "')>0 ORDER BY Library", _
          cnx, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    Do While Not rsLIB.EOF
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c).Value = rsLIB!Library
        rsLIB.MoveNext
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    c = 3
    rsLIB.Close
    r = r + 1
    rsDB.MoveNext
Loop
```